# NodeJS executing code in wrong order. Why?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-mysql

The code I've written is executing in blocks, rather than sequentially. 
As an example:

```
Task 1 result Task 1 result Task 1 result

Task 2 result Task 2 result Task 2 result

Task 3 result Task 3 result Task 3 result
```

I'd like the order of execution to be like this instead:

```
Task 1 result Task 2 result Task 3 result

Task 1 result Task 2 result Task 3 result

Task 1 result Task 2 result Task 3 result
```

My code:

```
var async = require('async');
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
});

function getFiles(dir,files_){
    files_ = files_ || [];
    if (typeof files_ === 'undefined') files_=[];
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    for(var i in files){
        if (!files.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        var _name = files[i];
        var name = dir+'/'+files[i];
        if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()){
            getFiles(name,files_);
        } else {
            files_.push(_name);
        }
    }
    return files_;
}

connection.connect(function(err) {

  if(err){
    console.log('error: '+err);
  }else{
    var directory = "products_json/13658/";
    var all_files = getFiles(directory);

    async.eachSeries(all_files, function( file, callback) {

      // Skip an iteration if the file is a mac .DS_STORE file
      if(file !== ".DS_Store"){

        console.log('Processing file ' + directory + file);

        fs.readFile(directory+file, function read(err, fileData){
          var productsData = JSON.parse(fileData); 
          async.eachSeries(productsData.results, function( product, callback2) {

            async.eachSeries(Object.keys(product), function( productKey, callback3) {

              var checkIfColumnExistsQuery = connection.query(
                "SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =  ? AND TABLE_NAME =  ? AND COLUMN_NAME =  ? LIMIT 0 , 30;",
                ['unisaver', 'products', productKey],
                function(err, rows, fields) {
                  // Create the field if it doesn't exist
                  if(rows.length == 0){
                    console.log(productKey + " --- "+ typeof product[productKey] + " --- "+ product[productKey]);

                    if( typeof product[productKey] === 'object' ){
                      var createColumnQuery = connection.query(
                        "ALTER TABLE ?? ADD ?? TEXT(1000);", 
                        ['unisaver.products', productKey]
                      );
                    }else if( typeof product[productKey] === 'string' ){
                      var createColumnQuery = connection.query(
                        "ALTER TABLE ?? ADD ?? VARCHAR(255);", 
                        ['unisaver.products', productKey]
                      );
                    }else if( typeof product[productKey] === 'number' ){
                      var createColumnQuery = connection.query(
                        "ALTER TABLE ?? ADD ?? INT(11);", 
                        ['unisaver.products', productKey]
                      );
                    }
                  }
                }
              );
              callback3();
            });

            // TODO: Insert a row
            callback2();

          });
        });
      }
      callback();
    }, function(err){
       console.log('finished');
    });
  }
});
```

The output I get is:

```
Processing file products_json/13658/0.json
Processing file products_json/13658/1.json
Processing file products_json/13658/10.json
price ----: .....
price ----: .....
price ----: .....
```

This means that the database queries are being executed only after all other work has been done. I'd like the queries to run within the loop and produce the following output instead:

```
Processing file products_json/13658/0.json
price ----: .....
Processing file products_json/13658/1.json
price ----: .....
Processing file products_json/13658/10.json
price ----: .....
```

What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix this? I'm so stuck on this problem :(

Comment: Do you understand asynchronous execution and what that means to the sequence of execution within your function?

Comment: Kind of. All I know is that synchronous code is blocking, asynchronous code isn't. Meaning that the program will continue executing code if it's after an asynchronous block. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, an asynchronous operation is started and then the rest of your code continues on running.  The asynchronous operation then completes sometime later in the future and at that time your callback is called to signify that specific operation has completed and the results are available.  Multiple asynchronous operations have no natural guaranteed completion order.  If you want to run asynchronous operations in a specific order, you have to write special code to do that.  The `async` library which you are using will help you do that (it has features to do that).

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your callbacks right away before your asynchronous requests are finished. Also, you only need one `async.eachSeries()` (where you call the `callback` when your mysql query is finished).